# Parsing array-in-struct references

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm working with a third party parser for a programming language that has arrays and structures. Assuming that Str is a structure type variable that contains an array called A, and I is an integer variable, for the following expression:

```
Str.A[I]
```

the parser produces the following expression tree (in pseudocode):

```
StructMember
(
    Left = "Str"
    Right = ArraySubscript
    (
        Left = "A"
        Right = "I"
    )
)
```

I was expecting something else:

```
ArraySubscript
(
    Left = StructMember
    (
        Left = "Str"
        Right = "A"
    )
    Right = "I"
)
```

Because when executing or generating code, you first resolve the structure member, then perform a subscript.

From the theoretical standpoint, shouldn't operations that are evaluated first be deeper in the syntax tree than the ones that are evaluated next? In other words, should this behavior be considered a bug in the parser?

EDIT for rici: if StrA is an array of structs, here's the tree I get:

```
StructMember
(
    Left = ArraySubscript
    (
        Left = "StrA"
        Right = "I"
    )
    Right = ArraySubscript
    (
        Left = "A"
        Right = "I"
    )
)
```

That was for expression StrA[I].A[I].

EDIT2: for expression S.A[I].T, here's what I get:

```
StructMember
(
    Left = "S"
    Right = StructMember
    (
        Left = ArraySubscript
        (
            Left = "A"
            Right = "I"
        )
        Right = "T"
     )
 )
```

That doesn't make much sense from execution sequence standpoint, either.

Comment: Does your language maybe allow you to write things like `Foo.(X+Y)` as a shortcut for `Foo.X + Foo.Y`?

Comment: It seems a bit odd to me, too, but there is no real theory of ASTs. Sometimes, parsing requirements (particularly when using LL grammars) force you into a grammar which is not quite what you'd want, and then the AST needs to be adjusted in a subsequent pass. Just out of curiosity, if A is an array of structs, what do you get for S.A[I].T ?

Comment: @sepp2k: not to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: To me your "I was expecting" assumption is wrong. AST is supposed to capture the language input following the syntax of the input language abstracting away punctuators, white spaces etc. Code generation, expression evaluation etc. typically occur in later phases using their own data structures (built out of AST). So in my opinion it is not a parser bug as your assumption about the purpose of the AST is incorrect. BTW: without specifying the language your question is unclear and can not be answered as "there is no real theory of ASTs" as pointed by @rici

Comment: Regarding your edit: What was the expression you got that tree for? I don't think you entered the same expression that rici asked about. If the expression you entered really contained two `.`s, then the tree you got as a result is completely bugged.

Comment: Can you show the tree for the actual expression that rici asked about? With two dots and only one array access? I'd still be curious about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most languages the right operand of the member access operator would be an identifier, not an expression. The grammar for that would look something like this:

```
expression ::=
    ...
    | expression '.' identifier
```

In that case the AST you got does not fit the grammar. In fact the `right` member of the `StructMember` node shouldn't even have type `expression`, but type `string` (or whatever you use to represent identifiers).

The tree that you got would be equivalent to `Str.(A[I])`, which isn't even valid syntax according to that grammar.

It is theoretically possible that the grammar of your language looks like this instead:

```
expression ::=
    ...
    | expression '.' expression
```

If that's the case, `Str.(A[I])` would be valid syntax and if the precedence of `.` is lower than that of array subscripts, `Str.A[I]` would indeed be parsed as `Str.(A[I])`, making the tree you got correct. This would be highly unusual and in a comment you said that to the best of your knowledge it is not the case.

So we must assume that the grammar of your language looks something like the first one I showed and your parser is either buggy or is not intended to give a tree that exactly matches the grammar.

Comment: Whether the tree matches the formal grammar is the true measure of parser bugginess.

Answer (score 1):

It might help to consider what information we might need for something simple like:

`X[i]`

Here, I would expect the parse tree to look something like:

`ArraySubscript
(
   Left = "X"
   Right = "i"
)`

Hence, for arrays, you need exactly the attributes Left and Right.
Whereas for references to a struct member, I expect the left side to refer to the struct and the right side of the parse-tree to refer to the struct attribute.  Consider for example, if the struct attribute was a simple type such as an integer, then the StructMember might look something like this:

`StructMember
(
   Left = "Str"
   Right = "simple"
)`

to refer to something like:

`Str.simple`

The results you are seeing are consistent with this simple breakdown of how to consider each attribute.

Comment: I'm unconvinced. Your primitive examples are impeccable, but for my specific case, there are two seemingly viable options - subscript on top vs. structmember on top. The question is - which one does the theory say is right. Both Left and Right in either element can be expressions.

Comment: See, A[I] is not a structure member. A is.

Comment: Ah.  I understand your issue.  The answer to your question will eventually be resolved by the order of operations and your binding rules.  If you place a higher operation precedence on resolving struct attribute membership, you will arrive at your result.  Or, if you resolve right-to-left, you arrive at your results.  If you resolve left-to-right or place higher operation precedence on array references, you will arrive at the result that you saw.  It's really a question of how the grammar is defined.

Comment: There's no way to resolve such an expression other than left-to-right. `A` only exists in the struct scope; there's no way to first resolve `A[I]`, then look at `Str`. The order of execution is unambiguous.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev That's not what's meant by "order of operations" here. That term is commonly used to refer to precedence. For example in `a + b * c`, the order of operations tells us that it's equivalent to `a + (b * c)` rather than `(a + b) * c` - it tells us nothing about the order in which `a`, `b` and `c` are evaluated. If the `.` operator took an expression as its right operand (which would be highly unusual), the order of operations could theoretically state that `Str.A[i]` is the same as `Str.(A[i])` and the semantics of that could still be that ...

Comment: ... `Str` is evaluated first, followed by the evaluation of `A[i]` in the context of `Str`. That said this is not how it works in most languages and your expectation is really the common one.

Comment: @Bill In the vast majority of languages the right operand to `.` is an identifier, so precedence doesn't even enter into it. `Str.A[I]` being parsed as `Str.(A[I])` (or the latter even making sense) would be highly unusual, so I don't think it's correct to say that that's the expected result.